# I wanting to reproject the vertices of my polygon. I have been able to achieve this for the bounds but having a bit of trouble with the vertices

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, javascript, polygon

I wanting to reproject the vertices of my polygon. I have been able to achieve this for the bounds but having a bit of trouble with the vertices.

```
           function onFeatureModified(event) {
           var bounds = event.feature.geometry.getBounds();
           var answer = "bottom: " + bounds.bottom + "\n";
           answer += "left: " + bounds.left + "\n";
           answer += "right: " + bounds.right + "\n";
           answer += "top: " + bounds.top + "\n";
           alert(answer);

           var mapProjv =  map.getProjectionObject();
           var epsg4326v = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
       var verticesNative = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
       var verticesLatLon = verticesNative.transform( mapProjv , epsg4326v  );
       var vertices = verticesNative;
           alert(verticesNative);
           }
```

Below code that works:

```
           var vertices = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
           alert(vertices);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event parameter returned on the `onFeatureModified` returns a single feature instead of an array of features. So `var verticesNative = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();` won't work.

Also you cannot call `.transform()` on an array, rather you need to call it on the geometries that are withing the array. For that you will need to loop through.

Try this code:

```js
   function onFeatureModified(event) {

       var bounds = event.feature.geometry.getBounds();
       var answer = "bottom: " + bounds.bottom + "\n";
       answer += "left: " + bounds.left + "\n";
       answer += "right: " + bounds.right + "\n";
       answer += "top: " + bounds.top + "\n";
       //alert(answer);

       var mapProjv = map.getProjectionObject();
       var epsg4326v = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

       //var verticesNative = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
       var verticesNative = event.feature.geometry.getVertices();

       var verticesLatLon = [];

       var alertString = "";

       for (var x in verticesNative) {
           verticesLatLon.push(verticesNative[x].clone().transform(mapProjv, epsg4326v));
           alertString += "Vertice " + x + ": " + verticesLatLon[x].toShortString() + "\n";
       }

       alert(alertString);
   }
```

Comment: Once again you are correct @CaptDragon. thank you:) Great Answer. You truly are a blessing to the Stack Community.